# How to view the maps of downloaded city using skobbler sdk on iPhone?

Tags: ios, objective-c, skmaps

On running the demo application using skobler sdk in iphone,am able to download the map of particular city,then where can I view the map of that particular downloaded city and how to fetch current latitude and longitude in ofline maps.Looking for guidance so that I can proceed further.

Comment: Your location comes from CoreLocation. You view them [using the example](http://developer.skobbler.com/getting-started/ios#sec05), making sure to keep the maps offline. Seriously, read the examples; there's enough code there to figure out how to do it.

Comment: ok.I wil check with that